# $\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}$/$\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}),\Bbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $0$

Tags: ring-theory

$\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}$/$\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}),\Bbb{Z})\cong\{0\}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Not sure how to see it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not true.  Are you sure you've written it correctly?

Comment: Thx. Let me rewrite it!

Comment: Any (presumably) $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism $\phi:(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\to\mathbb{Q}$ is the trivial one.  Note that for every $x\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $nx=0$.

Comment: If $A$ is a torsion Abelian group and $B$ is a torsion-free Abelian group then $\text{Hom}(A,B)=0$.

Comment: You rewrote the question, but not the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that by the universal property of the quotient $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$, $\operatorname{Hom}_\Bbb{Z}(\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z},\Bbb{Q})$ is in canonical bijection with $$S = \{f\in\operatorname{Hom}_\Bbb{Z}(\Bbb{Q},\Bbb{Q})\mid f(n) = 0\textrm{ for all }n\in\Bbb{Z}\}.$$ However, if $f\in S$ and $m/n\in\Bbb{Q},$ it follows that $$0 = f(m) = f(n\cdot m/n) = nf(m/n),$$ and since $\Bbb{Q}$ is torsion-free, this implies $f(m/n) = 0.$ As $m/n$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f = 0,$ and that $\operatorname{Hom}_\Bbb{Z}(\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z},\Bbb{Q}) = \{0\}.$